# PyQt QFileIconProvider class custom icons

Tags: python, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

I have a QTreeView with a QFileSystemModel to create a folder directory tree. As I am on Windows with the terrible default icons I want to create a few of my own (folder, network drive, etc). From reading the docs I see I need to create my own QFileIconProvider class and override the default icons. My question is how in the world do I do this in python? I found this post [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52380-Can-folder-color-be-changed-in-QTreeView-when-QFilesystemModel-displays-drives) which gives a C++ solution but I do not know enough to translate it.

Here's my code thus far:

```
class IconProvider(QtGui.QFileIconProvder):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IconProvider, self).__init__()

        folder_icon = QtGui.QIcon("folder.png") # what the heck do I do with this?

self.file_model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
self.file_model.setIconProvider(IconProvider())
self.browse_tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
self.browse_tree.setModel(self.file_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the [`icon()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html#icon) method of [`QFileIconProvider`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html) and return the icon according to the [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class IconProvider(QtGui.QFileIconProvider):
    def icon(self, fileInfo):
        if fileInfo.isDir():
            return QtGui.QIcon("folder.png") 
        return QtGui.QFileIconProvider.icon(self, fileInfo)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    file_model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
    file_model.setIconProvider(IconProvider())
    file_model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.currentPath());
    browse_tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
    browse_tree.setModel(file_model)
    browse_tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc, this make sense to me however when I try it I still get the old folder icon... I did find this link https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2006-October/014314.html which mentions the issue, but there is no example so I'm not sure how to implement it.